# Inverse of a piecewise floor function

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

Given the following definitions

$$
y(x) = \left\lfloor{ (x - n + a - b)/a }\right\rfloor
,\quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
$$
z(x) = \max (0, y(x)),
$$
where $x, y(x), z(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ are positive integer variables and $a,b,n$ are constants.

I am trying to find an expression for $x(z)$. Somehow, I arrived at the following expression

$$
x(z) =
\begin{cases}
\max (0,\left\lceil{ a(z-1) + n + b }\right\rceil), & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

which works for $a <= 1$. I must have made a mistake when inverting, since for $a > 1$ this formula is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: A lower and upper bound for the inverse would also be pertinent for my application. The expression I found seems to be an upper bound for $a <= 1$, however I didn't prove it thoroughly.

Comment: What is $z$?  You treat $x$ a variable and rest as a constant  (and so you treat $y$ as function of $x$)? What does mean $\max(0,y)$? Is it supposed to be $z(x)=\max(0, y(x))$?  Either ways it's doubtful your question is answerable as the floor function is not invertible.

Comment: @Antares I edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.